# Proving that $f_n(x)=x^n$ does not converge on $[0,1]$ under the $L_1$ metric

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

We see that the pointwise limit is $f(x)=1$ if $x=1$, and $f(x)=0$, for $x\in[0,1)$. (our background space is $C[0,1]$)

How would one go about proving if $f_n\to f$? My feeling is that we do not have convergence, since the limit is  not continuous.

But since $f=1$ at only one point, would it be fair to argue:

$d_1(f_n,f)=\int_0^1|f_n-f|dx=\int_0^1x^ndx=\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$

Comment: Yes, the sequence converges to $0$ in the $L^1$-norm.

Comment: @DanielFischer, even if $C[0,1]$ is our background space? so it converges to a function outside of the space? Also is the integration I put forward justified?

Comment: You are right, the sequence $f_n$ is cauchy under the $L^1$ norm but not convergent, because the space is not complete under the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: It converges to $0$. The limit belongs to $C[0,1]$. $L^1$-convergence does not imply pointwise convergence. To show that $C[0,1]$ is not complete in the $L^1$-norm, you need a sequence that converges to a limit that has no continuous representative in $L^1([0,1])$.

Comment: @DanielFischer but the limit is not $f=0$, it is $f=1$, if $x=1$ and $f=0$ if $x\in[0,1)$

Comment: $L^1$ convergence does not imply pointwise convergence. In the $L^1$-norm, a sequence of functions can converge to a function without converging pointwise. $f_n(x) = x^n$ gives an example of that. $$\lVert f_n - 0\rVert_{L^1} = \lVert f_n\rVert_{L^1} = \int_0^1 \lvert f_n(x)\rvert\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1} \to 0.$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, so would it be sufficient that to say since $f_n\to 0\ne f$ under the $d_1$ metric, and since limits are unique in a metric space, $f_n$ cannot converge to $f$?

Comment: $f$ does not belong to $C[0,1]$, so $f_n$ cannot converge to $f$ in $C[0,1]$ regardless of which topology we use there. In $L^1$, we have $f = 0$, since the elements of $L^1$ are equivalence classes of functions with respect to equality almost everywhere.

Comment: Okay, brilliant, thank you for your help, I would be happy to accept this as an answer if you wish to post it :), and likewise for your help on my other questions.